Are these expansion joints or just decorations that I should cover before installing outdoor tiles on this concrete slab porch?
I have this 6'x8' concrete slab porch. It has a roof above and it is exposed to elements from two directions (frond and left side). The left side has a 1' built in planter along that entire side.
should I patch those groves before installing outdoor tiles (2cm x24"x36")
I am considering applying a concrete resurfacer for the rest of the area but I might need to use some fast patch to cover those groves
https://www.quikrete.com/athome/concreteresurfacer.asp


Use the proper tile thinset mortar for the tiles you are planning to use. Also use a notched trowel sized to the tile manufacturer's recommendations.
When you are installing your tiles, fill the grooves  with the same thinset. Just wipe some mortar in with the flat side of the trowel.
Apply the thinset and grove it with the proper size notch.
Set your tiles.
Grout after 24 hours.
Done.

Those are decorative, if they were expansion they would need to need to penetrate the full depth of slab.
If the layout of your edge of your new tiles lines up with the grooves I might fill the grooves, but I would likely just fill with the grout that I was setting tiles with.

the tiles are larger than those squares and they won't align. They are also very thick (20mm) so I am not sure if the grout will hold or reach at that depth

I can't select your answer because I am not clear what to do with them. Agree with the explanation that they are decorative and more to control or limit where the cracks would go if any

"Not clear what to do with them?"  NoSparks told you that they're just gonna be filled with whatever thinset you use to set your tiles.  Or are your tiles not supposed to be adhered to the slab?
